# Data binding with static properties in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, static

I have a simple static property `FontSizeTitle` which is supposed to be used for the stylised title in all instances of `HandledWindow` type, and update from the same static property at the same time without explicit notification after changing the property. by the settings panel or whatever that will change the property in order to change **and update** font sizes for all titles for all windows visually.

Here is the code of my stylised title in XAML, which is part of a template for the `HandledWindow`, which is part of a standard XAML style page, which is loaded by a resource dictionary from another library at startup. so it applies for all `HandledWindow` instances that will appear in the application:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TitleText"
       TextWrapping="Wrap"
       Text="Window Title"
       FontSize="{Binding Source={x:Static UI:HandledWindow.FontSizeTitle}, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
       VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
       FontFamily="{DynamicResource FontFamiliy}" />
```

Here is my simple static property, Note that binding actually works for the first time only.

```
public static double FontSizeTitle
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

By the base constructor of `HandledWindow` type it is set to 15, That size is working, But if setting it once again to another size after the initialisation the visual title won't update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure, what version of WPF you are using. WPF 4.5 now supports Binding and Property Change notifications for Static Properties.

Refer to this Blog [post](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties) for full discussion.

So, your HandledWindows class will become something like:

```
public static class HandledWindow
{
    private static double _fontSizeTitle;

    public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;

    static HandledWindow()
    {
        FontSizeTitle = 15;
    }

    public static double FontSizeTitle
    {
        get { return _fontSizeTitle; }
        set
        {
            _fontSizeTitle = value;
           StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(FontSizeTitle)));
        }
    }
}
```

And the Binding in XAML will become:

```
FontSize="{Binding Path=(local:HandledWindow.FontSizeTitle), Mode=OneWay}"
```

Comment: @adminSoftDK are you using .net 4.5?

Comment: yes, i have a static property, which i want to bind to, that delegate is always null, or just the empty delegate if i assign it to = delegate{ }