# One way binding to Static property doesn't update the target when source changes

Tags: wpf, binding, static

I have a static property, inside a static class, that i have bound to Source property of a frame. It is a OneWay binding. The binding is correctly working the first time but doesn't update the target when property changes. This is my xaml

```
<Frame x:Name="frmMain" Source="{Binding Source={x:Static currentPage:ActivePages.MainFramePage}, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

This is my static class  ActivePages.cs

```
public static class ActivePages
    {
        private static Uri mainFramePage;
        public static Uri MainFramePage
        {
            get { return mainFramePage; }
            set
            {
                mainFramePage = value;
                MainFramePageChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MainFramePage"));
            }
        }
public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> MainFramePageChanged;
}
```

I followed [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588(v=vs.110).aspx#static_properties) and [another link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20322241/5913067)
How do i update it, when source changes??

Answer (score 0):

You can use Path property if it is WPF 4.5 or higher:

```
 <Frame x:Name="frmMain" Source="{Binding Path=(local:ActivePages.MainFramePage), NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588(v=vs.110).aspx#static_properties) the signature of a static property changed event is either

```
public static event EventHandler MyPropertyChanged;
```

or

```
public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
```

So yours should be

```
public static event EventHandler MainFramePageChanged;
```

instead of

```
public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> MainFramePageChanged;
```

---

However, if you have multiple static properties, you should better use a single event

```
public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;
```

with `PropertyChangedEventArgs` that provide property name information.

---

You should also use this syntax for the Binding expression:

```
Source="{Binding Path=(currentPage:ActivePages.MainFramePage)}"
```

---

See also [this blog post](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties) for details about static property change notification.

Comment: i am not able to access the link for the blog. and your syntax for specifying the source doesn't load the frame source

Comment: Ok, the link seems to be broken, maybe just temporarily. The binding expression syntax may not work with older WPF versions. What version are you using? You may also take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41823852/1136211

Comment: And of course the binding path should be `currentPage:ActivePages.MainFramePage`, not `local:ActivePages.MainFramePage`.

Comment: Can you let me know the contents of the blog, cuz the link is still broken